# How to get multiple count in single query

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of Student which has fields

```
ID  |   Name        |   Class   |  
---------------------------------
1   |   One         |   Class1  |  
2   |   Two         |   Class2  |  
3   |   Three       |   Class1  |
```

I want to get the count of students for each class in a single Query. 
Like.

```
Class   |   Count   |
---------------------
Class1  |   2       |
Class2  |   1       |
```

Comment: It would be great if you could show some kind of effort on your part.

Comment: This is basic group by statement which you can construct on your own if you know the basics, you can learn more about SQL Group by on [W3Schools -  Group By](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT
 Class,
 COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM
  Student 
GROUP BY
  Class
```

Comment: What to do if a condition also to be added ?

Comment: WHERE your_condition
GROUP BY Class;